# Not able to get selected element in select element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an API which returns a JSON element in this format

```
{
    "XYZ": ["xyz","abc"],
    "ABC": ["cde","abc"],
    "CDE": ["bla","blla"]
}
```

I have to add those elements in dropdown, for that html code is

```
<select  class="ui search dropdown selection" ng-options="v for (v,k) in <API returns JSon>" style ="select:invalid { color: gray; }" ng-model="xyz">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Element</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='saveData(xyz)'>Save</button>
```

And my directive is

```
angular.module('member').directive('memberDirective',function(){
    templateUrl: "../../XYZ/xyz.html",
    controller: 'appConttroller',
    link: function($scope){
        $scope.saveData = function(data){
             console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Now the main problem is even if user selects any one of the value from dropdown and clicks **Save** button, in console log I can see its corresponding value.

Like for example if user selects **XYZ** and click **Save** button, in console log I can see **["xyz","abc"]**. But I want value whatever user has selected, not its corresponding value.
So can anyone suggest how to achieve this? For all other select elements in my Program I get value from ng-model only don't know why here it's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`select as`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-) syntax from the [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive like so:

```
<select class="ui search dropdown selection" ng-options="v as v for (v,k) in json" style ="select:invalid { color: gray; }" ng-model="xyz">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden >Select Element</option>
</select>
```

```js
(function() {

  angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ['$scope']

  function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.json = {
      "XYZ": ["xyz", "abc"],
      "ABC": ["cde", "abc"],
      "CDE": ["bla", "blla"]
    }
    
    $scope.saveData=function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController">


    <select class="ui search dropdown selection" ng-options="v as v for (v,k) in json" style="select:invalid { color: gray; }" ng-model="xyz">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Element</option>
    </select>
    
    <p>Value of ngModel: {{xyz}}</p>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='saveData(xyz)'>Save</button>


  </div>


</div>
```